# SWT Pressing ENTER Button event handler

Tags: java, events, swt

I'm trying to handle the event of pressing "enter button" when typing in a SWT Text field. Here is what I've done so far:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
                //do something here....
            }
        }
    });
```

This actually works when I hit Enter button, but not when I hit the enter button on the numpad.

Someone knows the constant variable for this button?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with:

```
if (arg0.keyCode==SWT.CR || arg0.keyCode==SWT.KEYPAD_CR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a traverse listener which is intended for handling things like Enter:

```
textField.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void keyTraversed(final TraverseEvent event)
    {
      if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN)
        { 
          ...
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain what are the differences between traverse listener vs key listener and why Enter event is handled by SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN? Thanks